# How can you format a laptop for which you don't have the right driver CDs?

Tags: laptop, formatting

I have a very old 400ish RAM laptop which I use with my family, but it hasn't been formatted for 5 years. As years passed junk bundled up on the laptop and now it's running horribly slow, even for a 400 RAM laptop.

Anyhow, this would all be fixed if I could format it. I have a Silicon Integrated Graphics card driver on it which I have no CD for. I don't even know all the drivers needed for it (But if that is a problem I could find out) and I wish to format it for a fresh start.

Is there a program that can help you with the driver installation without the need to keep your shelves full of driver CDs/floppies? I've heard something about a driverpack sollution program but I don't know what that is. If you could show me some sollutions and explain them in detail I would be very grateful.

EDIT: For further reference, by "format" I mean reinstalling windows and formatting the C drive (Since that affects performance most)

Comment: Perhaps backup your old drivers, *before formatting*? http://superuser.com/questions/262012/how-can-i-transfer-old-drivers-to-a-new-windows-installation http://superuser.com/questions/40403/best-drivers-backup-and-maybe-update-software http://superuser.com/questions/151887/how-can-i-backup-my-windows-xp-drivers http://superuser.com/questions/29704/how-do-i-go-about-backing-up-saving-installed-device-drivers-in-windows-2000-xp In fact, since it's a rather old laptop, the hard drive shouldn't be too big. Backup everything if possible, just in case, maybe even take a drive image.

Comment: in addition to what has been mentioned, something like si sandra, some software to "audit" your pc, might tell you something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few options. Windows often can grab generic drivers that will work well enough, and you can add on drivers from the OEM's website. You can also copy out the drivers for your hardware with something like [driverbackup](http://sourceforge.net/projects/drvback/).

You can also get a proper windows install cd, and add drivers from [driverpack](http://driverpacks.net/) with something like nlite - [the driverpacks project has a step by step guide here](http://driverpacks.net/docs/beginners-guide-windows-xp)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to find out the Make and Model of Graphics chip used, along with the Network Adaptor, Sound card and any other 'non-integrated into Windows' hardware you'll need additional drivers for after a reinstall from documentation given with your laptop, or online medium (.pdf's) from the laptop maufacturors website. Or if all else fails - by googling around with the laptop make and model.

Once you have these you should be able to do searches for installation drivers for the different products from their respective websites.

It really depends on the make/model as to how many different drivers you'll need, what's inbuilt in Windows aswell as to how easy they are to find.

Example: [Hp website with a list of drivers for a HP-G61-300 Laptop](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=4062&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=4041450) (after a windows reinstall these would be all you needed - Hardware and driver wise anyway, software you would need seperately.)